# Error While Creating JToolBar

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, action, jtoolbar

[image: All buttons are added fine apart from the color buttons]
I get this error while adding buttons to a toolbar
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: Sketcher.SketcherFrame$ColorAction cannot be cast to javax.swing.Icon`

ColorAction is a class to create toolbar buttons that change the background color of the JFrame. It extends `javax.swing.AbstractAction`.
Buttons of type `ColorAction` are stored in a `ColorActions[]` array and have their `SMALL_ICON` property set to appropriate values.

**Stack Trace**:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: Sketcher.SketcherFrame$ColorAction cannot be cast to javax.swing.Icon
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.setIconFromAction(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.configurePropertiesFromAction(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.setAction(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JButton.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Sketcher.SketcherFrame.addToolBarButton(SketcherFrame.java:182)
    at Sketcher.SketcherFrame.createToolbar(SketcherFrame.java:174)
    at Sketcher.SketcherFrame.<init>(SketcherFrame.java:27)
    at Sketcher.Sketcher.createGUI(Sketcher.java:16)
    at Sketcher.Sketcher.access$1(Sketcher.java:15)
    at Sketcher.Sketcher$1.run(Sketcher.java:10)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Highlighted Methods**

```
private void createColorMenu() {
    createElementColorActions();
    colorMenu = new JMenu("Color");
    colorMenu.setMnemonic('M');
    createRadioButtonDropDown(colorMenu,colorActions,blueAction);
    menuBar.add(colorMenu);
}
```

and

```
private void createRadioButtonDropDown(JMenu menu, Action[] actions,Action selected){
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        JRadioButtonMenuItem item = null;
        for(Action action : actions){
            group.add(menu.add(item = new JRadioButtonMenuItem(action)));
            if(action==selected){
                item.setSelected(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

and

```
private void addToolBarButton(Action action){
        >>JButton button = new JButton(action);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(2,5,5,2),
                            BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder()));
        button.setHideActionText(true);
        toolBar.add(button);
    }
```

and

```
private void createToolbar(){
        for(FileAction action : fileActions){
            if(action!=exitAction && action!=closeAction){
                addToolBarButton(action);
            }
        }
        toolBar.addSeparator();
        for(ColorAction action : colorActions){
            >>addToolBarButton(action);
        }
        toolBar.addSeparator();
        for(TypeAction action : typeActions){
            addToolBarButton(action);
        }
    }
```

**Constants File containing paths to images**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
public class SketcherConstants {
    public final static int LINE = 101;
    public final static int RECTANGLE = 102;
    public final static int CIRCLE = 103;
    public final static int CURVE = 104;

    public final static int DEFAULT_ELEMENT_TYPE = LINE;
    public final static Color DEFAULT_ELEMENT_COLOR = Color.blue;

    public final static String imagePath = "H:/Fasih/SketcherIcons/";
    public static final Icon NEW16 = new ImageIcon(imagePath+"new.GIF");
    public static final Icon OPEN16 = new ImageIcon(imagePath+"open.GIF");
    public static final Icon SAVE16 = new ImageIcon(imagePath+"save.GIF");
    public static final Icon PRINT16 = new ImageIcon(imagePath+"print.GIF");
    public static final Icon SAVEAS16 = new ImageIcon(imagePath+"saveas.GIF");

    public static final Icon LINE16 = new ImageIcon(imagePath+"line.PNG");
    public static final Icon CURVE16 = new ImageIcon(imagePath+"curve.PNG");
    public static final Icon RECTANGLE16 = new ImageIcon(imagePath+"square.PNG");
    public static final Icon CIRCLE16 = new ImageIcon(imagePath+"circle.PNG");

    public static final Icon RED16= new ImageIcon(imagePath+"red.GIF");
    public static final Icon GREEN16= new ImageIcon(imagePath+"green.GIF");
    public static final Icon YELLOW16= new ImageIcon(imagePath+"yellow.GIF");
    public static final Icon BLUE16= new ImageIcon(imagePath+"blue.GIF");
}
```

and

```
class ColorAction extends AbstractAction {
        public ColorAction(String name,Color color){
            super(name);
            this.color = color;
        }
        public ColorAction(String name,Color color,char ch,int modifiers){
            this(name,color);
            putValue(ACCELERATOR_KEY,KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(ch,modifiers));
            int index = name.toUpperCase().indexOf(ch);
            if(index!=-1){
                putValue(DISPLAYED_MNEMONIC_INDEX_KEY,index);
            }
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            elementColor = color;
            getContentPane().setBackground(color);
        }
        private Color color;
    }
```

If I remove the color buttons then the open, close, save buttons are added just fine. I have no idea why these cant be added.

Comment: Can you include the code for the ColorAction

Comment: Included the code for ColorAction..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please indicate the exact line in your code that triggered this exception. Looking at the stack trace, I'd assume that's SketcherFrame.java line 153. It'd be easier to debug.

But even without that, your problem seems to be that you are confusing `AbstractAction` for an `Icon`. Whatever threw the Exception was expecting an implementation of `Icon` and you gave it an implementation of `AbstractAction`.

I can suggest two things:

1. Implement `Icon` in `SketcherFrame$ColorAction` as well. You can implement multiple interfaces anyway. But...
2. ...in my opinion, creating a class that is both an `AbstractAction` and an `Icon` is a bad design decision. Since that you seem to be utilizing inner classes, just create an inner class implementing `Icon` and pass it to whatever triggers that exception.

Comment: See, the paths to images are stored as constant values of type Icon (in a constants file) and the SMALL_ICON (now changed to LARGE_ICON_KEY) have these values.
All the other buttons (8 of 12) are being added fine.
I'll mark the code, hold.

Comment: Done, new stack trace (which magically appeared) and the lines being flagged have been marked with >>

Comment: Hmmm...what Java are you using? I'm checking the docs of Java 6 and Java 7 for `AbstractButton` and can't seem to find a method named `setIconFromAction`. Links: Java 6 -- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html , Java 7 -- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html

Comment: BTW, if you have Java configured for terminal invocation, you can check by `java -version` or `javac -version`. If you are using an IDE, just search for how you can check your Java version in that IDE as it may differ.

Comment: well, I was just typing the code from a Java reference book. According to the author this is supposed to work fine. Just dont know why it won't work with me

Comment: When was that book published (see copyright page)? It is possible that it is invoking deprecated code and so the latest Java environments are having trouble with it. BTW, official toolbar tutorial for Java is at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html

Comment: NEVERMIND, THE ERROR WENT AWAY. IT WAS DUE TO A SPELLING MISTAKE.